Does “You all” sound too southern?
Multiple people made me dinner tonight. How do I say the following without sounding too country?

Thank y’all for dinner.

(I got made fun of in San Diego for saying y’all and now I'm sensitive). I already considered:

Thank you everyone for dinner.

but that is not natural enough.

Thank you for dinner.

That doesn't work because the connotation is that you is singular, i.e. I need to address all the cooks.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

It is also a matter of pronunciation and pausing. If you pronounce well your two words you and all without joining them in one syllable (y'all), there should not be an issue.
Otherwise, you can always say with emphasis:

Thank you, all of you, for this dinner tonight.

or without emphasis:

I want/would like to thank all of you for dinner.

or again, (as suggested by @Lambie)

I want to thank you all for dinner.


Yes, but also: I want to thank you all for dinner. That is not southern, as it were.

Many thanks to the (great) chefs/hosts who made me dinner tonight !

I like the flexibility you've added for 'great'! :-)

There's also a slightly less formal (Bill and Ted) manner...

Thanks, everyone, for a most excellent meal.

Or you could even just look at everyone and make sweeping gestures, while saying simply:

Thank-you for creating such an excellent meal.

Maybe this is more about reading your audience, first.

Those classy San Diegans should not have made fun of you for sounding like a southerner. In the Philly metro area its not uncommon to hear or see people using y'all, and nobody would consider this area to be "Southern".
But y'on down south, some of my kin would say the correct "Southern" wording would be...

Thank all y'all for dinner.


While true, this seems to offer the opposite of what was asked for.

@AndyBonner - the question is "Does “You all” sound too southern?", to which I have answered "No" and given an example of what would sound too southern.

The most obvious solution is:

Thanks for dinner!

This avoids the issue that the OP mentioned, namely that you might be construed as singling out one particular person as the addressee.

Meaning is created by context. Especially, the antecedents of pronouns are determined by context. If it's unclear whether "you" is plural or singular, simply make the context clearer.

Hey everybody! Thank you for dinner!

Or, if the cooks are fewer than "everybody," maybe call them out specially:

This has been fun! Monica, Bob, Lewis, thank you so much for cooking!

